# codeigniter chain query keyword issue

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, indexing, chain

why i got error?
please write the right syntax

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN, `log_out_time` as OUT, `hour_count` as Hours, `status` as Status
FROM (`hr_e' at line 1

```
SELECT `log_date` as DATE, `log_in_time` as IN, `log_out_time` as OUT, `hour_count` as Hours, `status` as Status
FROM (`hr_employee_attendence`)
WHERE `employee_id` =  '2001170036'
AND `log_date` >= '2017-11-01'
AND `log_date` <= '2017-11-30'

        $query = $this->db->select("log_date as DATE, log_in_time as IN, log_out_time as OUT, hour_count as Hours, status as Status")
                ->where($where)
                ->get("hr_employee_attendence");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keyword as string by doing below codeigniter chain query.

```
$chain_query = $this->db->select("log_date as 'DATE', log_in_time as 'IN', log_out_time as 'OUT', hour_count as 'Hours', status as 'Status', is_late as is_late")
                            ->get_where("hr_employee_attendence", [
                                "employee_id" => $employee_id,
                                "date(log_date) >= date('".$month_day_start."')" => NULL,
                                "date(log_date) <= date('".$month_day_end."')" => NULL,
                                "is_approved" => 1
                            ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`IN` is reserved word, you can't use it as a `alias`. Change it to another one.

```
$this->db->select("log_date as DATE, log_in_time as login ...
```

Comment: To other readers:  Notice how the error message (`... near 'IN, ...`) pointed directly at the spot to stare at.

Comment: Thanks..
but .. row syntax is work


 $selct_query = "SELECT `log_date` AS `DATE` , `log_in_time` AS `IN` , `log_out_time` AS `OUT` , `hour_count` AS `Hours` ,  `status` AS `Status`
        FROM `hr_employee_attendence`
        WHERE `employee_id` = '$employee_id'
        AND `log_date` >= '$month_day_start'AND
        `log_date` <= '$month_day_end'";
        $query = $this->db->query($selct_query);